# How to find real RTMP address from URL?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, rtmp

I found this code from console of browser. How to find RTMP address from it?

```
<smil><head><meta base="rtmp://medya1.izmir.bel.tr/IBB_CANLI" /></head><body><switch live="true" isDVR="false"><video src="HalkapinarKavsagi.stream?wowzatokenstarttime=1474595548&wowzatokenendtime=1474655548&wowzatokenCustomParameter=myParameter&wowzatokenhash=IntLGCHdr-0yl7UMRjvf3aalPgNSs4pSd5vZfSBdViY=" system-bitrate="1080"/><video src="HalkapinarKavsagi.stream_480p?wowzatokenstarttime=1474595548&wowzatokenendtime=1474655548&wowzatokenCustomParameter=myParameter&wowzatokenhash=dtZSpAsFB3abC9AKqUvdVTFLqdhnkr4DuBPyU5I8TtY=" system-bitrate="480"/></switch></body></smil>
```

Webpage URL: http://kentkameralari.izmir.bel.tr/webservices?service=player&streamId=60

Also I have captured this part from [URLHelper](http://www.urlhelper.com):

```
rtmp://medya1.izmir.bel.tr:1935/IBB_CANLI<playpath>HalkapinarKavsagi.stream_480p?wowzatokenstarttime=1474595548&wowzatokenendtime=1474655548&wowzatokenCustomPÂ <swfUrl>http://kentkameralari.izmir.bel.tr/lib/player/flash/Ivme.swf <pageUrl>http://kentkameralari.izmir.bel.tr/webservices?service=player&streamId=60
```

I tried `rtmp://medya1.izmir.bel.tr:1935/IBB_CANLI/HalkapinarKavsagi.stream_480p` address on RTMP-Player, but I could not play.

Comment: How to find RTMP address from it ... Did u mean : How to retrieve `medya1.izmir.bel.tr` from `rtmp://medya1.izmir.bel.tr/IBB_CANLI`

Comment: I mean that there is a live video streaming URL that is based flash player. I would like to retrieve RTMP address of video. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you interact with the *flash app* ? if not, then you wont have much luck getting the actual stream URL - not that having that URL will help as browsers don't "do" RTMP anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rtmp address was encrypted with "Wowza SecureToken" protection system.

We can see that the address has path like this:

```
HalkapinarKavsagi.streamwowzatokenstarttime=1474678923&wowzatokenendtime=1474738923&wowzatokenCustomParameter=myParameter&wowzatokenhash=v1KLeJHt_NAtTYlIecZMAzXorZ4X4hNGo5m5uNSu2C0=
```

That's why I could not play on [RTMP Player](https://www.hlsplayer.net/rtmp-player).

Best regards.